# Edge length in an EMST

Tags: computational-geometry, probability-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Consider a domain on a unit grid such that the grid nodes hold a point with probability $\frac12$. We construct a Euclidean minimum spanning tree on these points.

How could we compute the probability that an edge of the tree is of unit length (so it joins two immediate grid neighbors) ?

[image]

The probability that a point has an immediate grid neighbor is $1-\left(\frac12\right)^4=\frac{15}{16}$, but this does not account for the fact that not all immediately neighboring points pairs make an edge of the tree. The domain can be taken arbitrarily large, to avoid border effects.

Comment: Nice question, but I think your example is not an EMST: there should be an edge between $(3, 1)$ and $(4, 1)$ instead of $(3,2)$ and $(4,1)$ (given the left-bottom vertex is $(0,0)$).

Comment: @Nathaniel: this is likely. The sketch was made by hand, just to illustrate. There could be other mistakes.

Comment: Thats a really good question! It is actually equivalent to asking what is the expected number of "cliques" containing only neighboring nodes, since the number of "red" edges is exactly one less than that (it generates a tree on the super-graph). So the probability is exactly $\frac{E[num points] - 1}{E[num points] - E[num cliques] - 2}$. So finding the probability has some interesting implications!

Comment: @nirshahar: what do you call the super-graph ? Do those cliques correspond to the green subtrees ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Are you interested in exact answers on $p$, or bounding $p$?

Comment: @AspiringMat: an upper bound is fine... if it is tight enough. :-)

Comment: @AspiringMat: are you sure about that ? In any case, non uniqueness can be handled the way that is most convenient. Notice that the next integer distance is 2 (you have to trade integers for integers), and points with no closer neighbor will be rare.

Comment: @Yves, yes, those cliques correspond one to one with the green subtrees